# Email Response Code

Tags: email, smtp, status

I am having problem with understanding below given response codes:

support @ webiindex.com     250 Accepted

support @ webnode.com       250 2.1.5 Ok

support @ topcities.com     250 2.1.5 OK dc5si179569wib.22 - gsmtp

support @ skynet.be         250 recipient  ok
support @ worldwidehealth.com   250 Ok

*(I am using an online tool for verifying my email ids.)*

Can anybody here help me with understanding these status codes?

Thanks,

Hemant

Answer (score 1):

The format of SMTP reply codes is explained in [section 4.2 of RFC2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.2.1).

Codes starting with 2xx indicate a positive reply, i.e. the command was successful. If the email address was invalid you would likely get a 5xx error of some kind, or possibly 4xx.

More specifically, response 250 means "Requested mail action okay, completed". However note that that is not the only valid response you might receive.

The rest of the data in the response looks to be server specific - i.e. there is no defined format. If they were using the [`VRFY` command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.1.1.6), the response should have included the verified address in one of these two forms:

```
  User Name <local-part@domain>
  local-part@domain
```

That suggests they are probably verifying the address in some other way - possibly by sending a [`RCPT TO` command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.1.1.3).